# css to format line 1 and 2 of my h1 differently? & change position of line break

Tags: css, padding, line-breaks, pseudo-element

Hi I am using a featured post widget in  wordpress and its is displaying my h1 heading over 2 lines. However I want to change the margin or line breaks so that instead of saying
"Workplace Injury" on the first line and "Prevention" on the second line,
It would say "Workplace" on the first line and "Injury Prevention" on the second

Any ideas. I've tried using a psuedo first line command but no luck ie.

```
#home-header-right .featuredpage .post-7  h2:first-line,
#home-header-right .featuredpage .post-20  h2:first-line, 
#home-header-right .featuredpage .post-7  a:first-line,
#home-header-right .featuredpage .post-20  a:first-line  {
    padding: 0 50px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: `:first-line` is unfortunately not useful for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The selection of text that is selected by `:first-line` is an inline-level block of text and cannot have padding and margin applied to it. You could try setting `display: block` on it to see if it works, but as far as the [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/%3afirst-line) goes, you can only use the following CSS properties on that text:

- `font` properties, `color`, `background` properties, `word-spacing`, `letter-spacing`, `text-decoration`, `vertical-align`, `text-transform`, and `line-height`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break the text on the first word, I recommend you just wrap it in another element:

```html
<h1><span>Workplace</span> Injury Prevention</h1>
```

```css
h1 span {
    display: block;
}
```

Example: http://dabblet.com/gist/1714493

The additional element is non-semantic, but less so than a hard-coded `<br>`, and more reliable than trying to mess with the `:first-line` pseudo-element.

**Edit:** If you can't use HTML in post titles and don't mind using a bit of jQuery, you could dynamically wrap the text like so:

```javascript
(function($) {
    $('h1:contains(Workplace Injury Prevention)')
        .html(function(i, html) {
            return html.replace('Workplace', '<span>Workplace</span>');
        });
    ;
})(jQuery);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/deZKd/

To do this for other post titles, you will want something more generic:

```javascript
(function($) {
    $('h1')
        .html(function(i, html) {
            return html.replace(/^(\w+)\b/, '<span>$1</span>');
        });
    ;
})(jQuery);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/deZKd/1/

(Bear in mind that in both these examples, you will want to change the selector to match only post headings within the widget, e.g. `#recent-posts-widget h1:contains(…)`.)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the title is being pulled from a featured post widget so I don't have the opportunity to wrap it in span tags. Thus there is no easy fix?

Comment: You could use `text-indent` to push the first few words over, but that would ruin the alignment. Since the effect is purely cosmetic, you can justifiably consider using JavaScript; I'll get back on that.